# Finding the order of elements of a product group

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let’s say I have two groups $G=\mathbb Z_{12}$ and $H=\mathbb Z_2^2×\mathbb Z_3$. I want to check if the two groups are isomorphic or not.

I clearly know that $G$ is cyclic. I consulted the answer sheet and the solution is something like this:

The two groups are not isomorphic because while all the elements of $H$ have order at most 6, $G$ has an element of order 12.

My question is how do I know the that the former is true? I guess checking with every element is one of the ways, but it can be really tedious.

Answer (score 0):

$Z_{mn} \cong Z_{m} \times Z_{n}$ iff $(m,n)=1$, that means greatest common divisor of $m$ and $n$ is one. Please note one more thing that isomorphism does not preserve order only it is much more than just preserving order.

Comment: But how do you deal with the other $\mathbb Z_2$ factor? How can you show that that does not increase the maximal order?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Suppose $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3$. Now $(a,b,c)^n=(a^n,b^n,c^n)$. We need $n=6$ to ensure that $b^n=1,c^n=1$ but that also suffices to give $a^n=1$. Now just noticed your deleted solution. You know all that! So why did you delete your solution? It was fine.

Comment: @almagest Because yours was upvoted, and mine wasn't (I don't like my answers to have precisely no score). Besides, I'm already maxed out for the day.